# Symfony2- What's the best way pre-filling an entity db table with default values?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've a question regarding best practices using *Symfony2*.

I want to pre-fill a doctrine entity db table with some default values. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great and easy to use bundle for that: [DoctrineFixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I seem to be blind by always missing the _bundles_ section in the documentation ;)